# Ionic2 Native Storage storing/retrieving Arrays

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic app in which I store an **Array** with Native-Storage. 
This **Array** is an array of objects.

**I stored it like this:**

*>>> array1: CertainType[]* With at least 50 shuffled elements

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('array1', { property: array1 })
   .then(
      () => { console.log('array1 stored') },
      error => { console.log('array1 not Stored',error)
});
```

**I retrieve the item like this:**

```
this.nativeStorage.getItem('array1').then(
    array1 => {  
       //On the Sucess of getting Array1 use it to create Array2
       array2 = array1.splice(0,5); //<-- MY PROBLEM IS HERE
    },
    error => {
        console.error('Error Getting Array', error);
    }
);
```

**I keep getting the Error of**

I thought its because the process of storing and retrieving was messing with the type of the array, etc.

I tried to do casting:

```
..array1 as CertainType[]
```

-- EDITED>>
I tried stringfying and JSONparsing.

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('array1', { property: JSON.stringify(array1)}).then(. . . .

array2 = JSON.parse(array1);
```

Throw this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

---

But i keep getting the same error on the splice().

If I not use the logic of storing, the code runs just fine.... Any clues. What am I missing? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSON stringify before store in localStorage cause it will return a promise 
just do this for example :

```
​var test = { test: "thing", test2: "thing2", test3: [0, 2, 44] }​​​​​​​;
localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(test));

var test2 = localStorage.getItem("test");
test = JSON.parse(test2);
```

Comment: I know :D
Bu the array has more than 5. By the way, the elements are all shuffled. I need to get and remove the first 5 elements. I just showed the code simplified. There's other logics in work here :D
Any guess?

Comment: I keep getting error, this time with JSON.Parse.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

I'll edit the question with the code I'm using.

Comment: Your answer was right. The Ionic documentation was wrong about the example they use. I answer my own question with the problem I faced. Thanks buddy!! :D

Answer (score 0):

The Ionic Native Storage Documentation confused me.

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

I sticked to the book and use almost equal code on my app. But that word **"property"** over there was breaking my floor.

The good contributor above me, insisted (thank god) on the use of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to save and retrieve the data.

So I did, but kept getting errors.  Then I realized: when I tried to retrieve the data, my Array was stored on an Object. Ok! But **UNDER** a *p-r-o-p-e-r-y* attribute..

If I did get my array1 using array1.property I would get what I was looking for.

In the end, just a little change will make it work like a clock:

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('array1', JSON.stringfy(array)})
      .then(. . .

this.storage.get('array').then( array1 => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(array1));
```